# Calling the API with pagination using Retrofit on Android

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I'm implementing retrofit in my android app for calls in my API.
I have in a call in my API many results, and then I decided to create a pagination in the API.
The return on my call API is the one below:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "server": "localhost",
        "offset": "1",
        "limit": "1",
        "recordCount": 1
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "userName": "ricardo"
        }
    ]
}

Call<BaseResponse<User>> user = userResource.getListUser(
                authController.getTokenHeader(),
                limit,
                offset
                );

        user.enqueue(new Callback<BaseResponse<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<BaseResponse<User>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    New Call Api Again if more results
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {}
       });
```

When I change the "offset" in the call I "step" to the next page.

Is there any retrofit method that does this logic for me?
If not, how could I implement this logic?

```
while (callApi){
            UserResource userResource = getRetrofit().create(UserResource.class);
            Call<BaseResponse<User>> user = userResource.getListUsers(
                    authController.getTokenHeader(),
                    ids,
                    cdCode,
                    limit,
                    offset
            );

            user.enqueue(new Callback<BaseResponse<User>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<BaseResponse<User>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {

                        offset = offset+offset;

                            callInvoice = false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: you can add params in api like give me result from 1 to 20, in another api 21 to 40 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create pagination in **api**. Call according to page, While your listview is scrolling call the page if not service is calling.

```
mOrdersView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
                    if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount
                            && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                            && totalItemCount >= CommonUtils.pageLimit) {
                        getNextPage();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

You can implement scroll listener like this

Comment: I think its very valid, but I'm not using recyclerView to populate my adapter and then make API calls.

I think I could put this call inside a while. But in the while the code is not working properly and is not entering inside the enqueue, can you tell me what explanation for this?

Comment: you can use setOnScrollListener for listview